# however, no matter how beautifully crafted your CSS, it is pretty useless on its own -- why is there no "is" after "your CSS"?

Tags: grammar

> However, no matter **how beautifully crafted your CSS**, it is pretty useless on its own.
>   Applying styles to well-formed (X)HTML is the first step that may seem arbitrary to you, but
>   this vital procedure is very often the first stumbling block for newcomers. Many seasoned
>   developers still fail to exploit the true flexibility of CSS at this stage, and never fully embrace the glory of the cascade.

I don't understand why there's no **is** after **how beautifully crafted your CSS**. I asked a native speaker, he said the sentence sounded alright to him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The verb-to-be in its various forms (here, the subjunctive) can be dropped in many situations.

No matter how beautifully crafted your CSS *may be*....

No matter how expensive your car, some day it will need to be repaired.